# How to list objects in a JSON file in html select options using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Firstly, my javascript knowledge is very very low and I'm struggling quite a bit hence the question. I understand there have been many similar questions, but what I need is for it to only use very basic javascript. 
So far I have:

JSON File:

```
var list=
    [
      {"title":"ObjectA",...
      },
      {"title":"ObjectB",...
      }
    ]
```

I've managed to list them using:

```
function objects() {
                for (a=0; a<list.length; a++) {
                    document.write(list[a].title);
                }
            }
```

However that puts all objects in one line. I know you can list them individually using something like:

```
function object0() {
                document.write(list[0].title)
            }
```

What I'm wondering is it is possible to list them using a for loop or something simple like that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

```js
var list=
    [
      {"title":"ObjectA"},
      {"title":"ObjectB"},
      {"title":"ObjectC"},
      {"title":"ObjectD"},
      {"title":"ObjectE"},
      {"title":"ObjectF"}
    ];

document.write('<select name="item">');
list.map(function(item) {
  document.write('<option>'+item.title+'</option>');
});
document.write('</select>');
```

Comment: `select` / `option` - not `ul` / `li` ?

Comment: @NickGrealy did not saw the title (:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list, null, 2);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

or print it to the console

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 2));
```

Working example:

```js
const list = [
  { 'title': 'ObjectA' },
  { 'title': 'ObjectB', foo: { ble: 123 } }
]

const pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list, null, 2);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```